# MySQL stored procedure returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

So I've created this stored procedure, where I made a check if the row with the values already exists or not, before implementing a new row to the database. If the row already exists, I return the existing ID of that row, else I return the newly created row ID.

The Stored procedure is:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE TestJobExists int;
    
    SELECT id into TestJobExists FROM TestJob 
WHERE `JobLink` = JobLink AND `StartTime` = StartTime 
    AND `Endtime` = Endtime 
    AND `Owner` = Owner_info AND `Engine` = Engine_info 
    AND (`TestSuiteId` = TestSuiteId or `TestSuiteId` is NULL)
    AND (`TestSuiteCollectionId` = TestSuiteCollectionId or 
      `TestSuiteCollectionId` is NULL) 
    AND `Finished` = Finished AND `JenkinsBuild` = JenkinsBuild 
    AND `JenkinsJobName` = JenkinsJobName;

    -- Set values to NULL if we have an empty string (we allow either null or ints)

    IF TestSuiteId = '' THEN
    SET TestSuiteId = null;
    END IF;
    
    IF TestSuiteCollectionId = '' THEN
    SET TestSuiteCollectionId = null;
    END IF;
    
    IF TestSuiteCollectionId != '' THEN
    SET TestSuiteId = null;
    END IF;

    -- If we have found an ID it should be above or equal to 1 else insert new row

    IF TestJobExists >= 1 THEN      
        SELECT TestJobExists AS LastInsertId;        
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO TestJob
(`id`,`JobLink`,`StartTime`,`Endtime`,`Owner`,`Engine`,`TestSuiteId`,`TestSuiteCollectionId`,`Finished`,`JenkinsBuild`,`JenkinsJobName`) 
VALUES (NULL, JobLink, StartTime, Endtime, Owner_info, Engine_info, TestSuiteId, TestSuiteCollectionId, Finished, JenkinsBuild, JenkinsJobName);
      SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS LastInsertId;          
    END IF; 
END
```

`TestJobExists` will be set to the existing ID or null if it doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist we insert a new row.

I tried to run the SQL query, which only returned a single row:

```
SELECT id into TestJobExists FROM TestJob 
WHERE `JobLink` = "https://www.test.com" 
   AND `StartTime` = "2022-05-02 08:36:07" 
   AND `Endtime` = "2022-05-02 09:24:23"
   AND `Owner` = "" AND `Engine` = "Tap" 
   AND (`TestSuiteId` = "" or `TestSuiteId` is NULL)
   AND (`TestSuiteCollectionId` = "462" or `TestSuiteCollectionId` is NULL) 
   AND `Finished` = "SUCCESS" AND `JenkinsBuild` = "537"
   AND `JenkinsJobName` = "VTU";
```

But when I call the stored procedure with exactly the same values it says that it cant return more than one row:

```
CALL CreateTestJob("https://www.test.com","2022-05-02 08:36:07","2022-05-02 09:24:23","","Tap","","462","SUCCESS","537","VTU")
```

So why does it return a single row when I run it for itself and why does it return multiple when it's inside the stored procedure?

My guess is that it's something to do with my understanding on how either this is used `(TestSuiteId = "" or TestSuiteId is NULL) AND (TestSuiteCollectionId = "462" or TestSuiteCollectionId is NULL)` or the way the SQL searches for the `DATETIME` rows `StartTime = "2022-05-02 08:36:07" AND Endtime = "2022-05-02 09:24:23"`

This is how the table looks:

```sql
Table: testjob
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
Timestamp timestamp 
JobLink varchar(300) 
JobNo int(11) 
StartTime datetime 
EndTime datetime 
Owner varchar(45) 
Engine varchar(100) 
TestSuiteId int(11) 
TestSuiteCollectionId int(11) 
Finished varchar(45) 
JenkinsBuild int(100) 
JenkinsJobName varchar(100) 
LogTimestamp varchar(45) 
JobVerdict varchar(45) 
logText longtext 
FlagStatus int(11) 
Delete int(11) 
Manuel int(11)
```

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I might be reading your code wrong. but you are saying the following in your SP,
First of you are inserting data, and do some null checks after that. Then you check if the entered ID already exist.  IF it does you do a select without a whare clause , where this will return everything else you insert again. in your stand alone select you have a where clause . which is why you get only 1 result. by adding the same  WHERE in your SP your problem should be solved.. but again I might be reading your code wrong

Comment: You are using parameters (i suppose since you haven't provided the create statement) with the same names as table column names , backticks are not sufficient to differentiate , change the parameter names.

Comment: I too face this issue. When the query is executed it gives 1 record but when the same is executed from an sp, the result is different.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after going through this link and several searches found that this and it worked for me.
Add this to the start of the sp.
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 0;